Trying to ban user as a super user (banned user can't create posts)
I give permission to my superuser to ban all the other types of users, this is my views.py file:
@login_required(login_url='login')
def Home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        #taking the id i passed in value attribute
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
        user_id = request.POST.get("user_id")
        

        if post_id:
            post = Post.objects.filter(id=post_id).first()
            if post and (post.auther == request.user or request.user.has_perm('main.delete_post')):
                post.delete()
        
        elif user_id:
            user = User.objects.filter(id=user_id).first()
            if user and request.user.is_staff:
                try:
                    group = Group.objects.get(name="default")
                    group.user_set.remove(user)
                    print("removed successfully")
                except:
                    print("something went wrong")
                    pass
                try:
                    group = Group.objects.get(name="mode")
                    group.user_set.remove(user)
                    print("removed successfully")
                except:
                    print("something went wrong")
                    pass

    return render(request,"main/home.html", {"posts":posts})


My html file:
{% if user.is_staff %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value={{post.id}} name="user_id">Ban User</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}

I tried to print messages if the user is removed and it removed printing successfully, but when I logged as that banned user I can still create post.
Did I miss something in views.py?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

when you press Ban User then you send post.id - why not user_id
